# How can I make this rectangle slow down?

Tags: processing

The rectangle is moving and when I click it needs to be moving at 0.1 instead of 3. I don't know how to code the mousePressed part so that it stays at 0.1 the whole time.

```
float stripeX = 0;

void setup() {

    size(500, 300);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);

    fill(10, 10, 100); 
    rect(stripeX, 90, 150, 250); 


    stripeX = stripeX + 3;
    stripeX = stripeX % width;
}

void mousePressed() {
    stripeX = stripeX - 2.9; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `mousePressed` variable along with an `if` statement inside the `draw()` function:

```java
float stripeX = 0;

 void setup() {
  size(500, 300);
 }

 void draw() {
  background(255);

  fill(10, 10, 100); 
  rect(stripeX, 90, 150, 250); 

  if(mousePressed){
    stripeX = stripeX + .1;
  }
  else{
    stripeX = stripeX + 3;
  }

   stripeX = stripeX % width;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way in Your case is to use mouseReleased() method:

```
float stripeX, deltaX;

void setup() {
    size(500, 300);
    stripeX = 0f;    // init values here, in setup()
    deltaX = 3f;
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(10, 10, 100); 
    rect(stripeX, 90, 150, 250); 
    stripeX += deltaX;
    stripeX = stripeX % width;
}

void mousePressed(){
   deltaX = 0.1;
}

void mouseReleased(){
   deltaX = 3f;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is all a bit dicey. How often is draw() called? On every frame? Generally it's a bad idea to adjust things in a draw function, it should just draw.

To hack it somewhat

```
float stripeX = 0;
float deltaX = 3.0;

void draw()
{
   //omitted some code
   stripeX += deltaX; 
}

void mousePressed()
{
    if(deltaX > 0.1)
        deltaX = 0.1;
    else
        deltaX = 3.0;  // let a second press put it back to 3.0
}
```

However you probably want to put it back to 3.0 on mouse up. You haven't
given enough information to know how to intercept that event.